# git shows files changed with 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

Tags: git

There are many times when I run a "git diff --shortstat" command and it outputs the following:

```
17 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Hows that possible that files changed even though there were no insertions or deletions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible if the file permissions have changed for some of the files in the project:

Sample Example:

```
$ git init && touch file && git add file && git commit -m "msg"
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/Desktop/test/.git/
$ chmod +x file
$ git diff --shortstat 
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

You can use `git config core.filemode false` to turn this feature off.

Comment: Note that it is only the executable bit that can cause a change, not the rw bits.  Also 'git diff' without --shortstat conveys this information.

Answer (score 5):

That generally happens for binary files, when there is no diff possible between one version to the other.

```
Binary files differ
```

See for instance this [diff in the Eclipse equinox project](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.binaries.git/commit/?id=9fad7ffe1eede5cd57b17f06e650a6e1b7c64b1e).