# Git says "1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)"

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I just created an HTML file that has 9 lines on my repository and I used "git commit -m" command but git said, "1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)".

I expected the output of "1 file changed, 9 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)" because I created a file that has 9 lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git shows files changed with 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053363/git-shows-files-changed-with-0-insertions-0-deletions)

Comment: Which command gives the output you are asking about?

Comment: Did you run `git add theHTMLfile` before or after adding the 9 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `git add` and `git commit` two commands then you can use this (for existing files)

`git commit -a -m 'your commit message'`

As per git documentation, Adding the -a option to the git commit command makes Git automatically stage every file that is **already tracked** before doing the commit, letting you skip the git add part.

For new files, you will need to explicitly add it using `git add`

Answer (score 2):

Before committing a new file, you need to add it to the "index" with

```
git add <filename>
```

Comment: If it's a totally new file, `git commit -a` won't add it to the index. You can use `git add -N` to create the index entry, but if you're going to do that, you might as well use `git add` without `-N` to just put the whole thing in. :-)

Comment: @torek I'll remove that part of my answer to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

May be you've created files in powershell window itself (eg. echo randomtext > random.txt). Try creating manually!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).